# Expectation of integral with Poisson-process increment

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, poisson-process

Let $N=(N_t)_{t\geq 0}$ be a Poisson process with jumping times $(T_i)_{i\in \mathbb N}$ and intensity $\lambda\in L^1_{loc}([0,\infty))$, i.e.
\begin{align}
E[N_t]=\int_0^t \lambda(s)ds, \forall t\geq 0.
\end{align}
The Stieltjes integral with respect to $N$ is defined by, for $f: [0,\infty)\longrightarrow \mathbb R$,
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty f(t)dN_t:=\sum_{i=1}^\infty f(T_i) 1_{T_i\leq +\infty}.
\end{align}
How can I prove that
\begin{align*}
E[\int_0^\infty f(t)dN_t] = \int_0^\infty f(t)\lambda(t) dt.
\end{align*}

I have no ideas to prove it because I don't know how to link it with the first identity.
Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: Typically this is proved using an approximation Argument. From the first identity you see that the assertion holds for $f(t)=1_{[0,T]}(t)$. Then, by linearity, the assertion also holds for step functions. Now, for general $f$, you need to approximate $f$ by step functions and use a continuity argument.

Comment: Yes, I understand the idea, thank you so much!